# Network error using Chocolatey to install programs

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, chocolatey

I have tried just about everything on https://chocolatey.org/install

Here is the error I get using the method most strongly recommended:

[image: commandPromptInstallError]

Per their instructions, I used PowerShell to

'Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned'

I have also tried performing the install from PowerShell

with the following result:

[image: chocolateyInstallPowerShellError]

I have also tried the "completely offline install" which involves manually downloading and extracting a nupkg file, but with similar results as the above. Do you have any insight into the errors I'm receiving? What should I do to get chocolatey installed?

Thank you in advance for any ideas you might have.

UPDATE: [Click Here](https://pastebin.com/S5hmYVrJ) for the chocolatey log file. Snippet below to satisfy SO requirement:

```
2017-04-26 11:47:33,091 [DEBUG] - Configuration:
CommandName='install'|
CacheLocation='C:\Users\PARAGON\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey'|
ContainsLegacyPackageInstalls='True'|
CommandExecutionTimeoutSeconds='2700'|WebRequestTimeoutSeconds='30'|
Sources='https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'|SourceType='normal'|
Debug='False'|Verbose='False'|Trace='False'|Force='False'|Noop='False'|
HelpRequested='False'|UnsuccessfulParsing='False'|RegularOutput='True'|
QuietOutput='False'|PromptForConfirmation='True'|AcceptLicense='False'|
AllowUnofficialBuild='False'|Input='choco'|AllVersions='False'|
SkipPackageInstallProvider='False'|PackageNames='choco'|
Prerelease='False'|ForceX86='False'|OverrideArguments='False'|
NotSilent='False'|ApplyPackageParametersToDependencies='False'|
ApplyInstallArgumentsToDependencies='False'|IgnoreDependencies='False'|
AllowMultipleVersions='False'|AllowDowngrade='False'|
ForceDependencies='False'|Information.PlatformType='Windows'|
Information.PlatformVersion='6.2.9200.0'|
Information.PlatformName='Windows 8'|
Information.ChocolateyVersion='0.10.5.0'|
Information.ChocolateyProductVersion='0.10.5'|
Information.FullName='choco, Version=0.10.5.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=79d02ea9cad655eb'|

Information.Is64BitOperatingSystem='True'|
Information.Is64BitProcess='True'|Information.IsInteractive='True'|
Information.IsUserAdministrator='True'|
Information.IsProcessElevated='True'|
Information.IsLicensedVersion='False'|Information.LicenseType='Foss'|
Features.AutoUninstaller='True'|Features.ChecksumFiles='True'|
Features.AllowEmptyChecksums='False'|
Features.AllowEmptyChecksumsSecure='True'|
Features.FailOnAutoUninstaller='False'|
Features.FailOnStandardError='False'|Features.UsePowerShellHost='True'|
Features.LogEnvironmentValues='False'|Features.VirusCheck='False'|
Features.FailOnInvalidOrMissingLicense='False'|
Features.IgnoreInvalidOptionsSwitches='True'|
Features.UsePackageExitCodes='True'|
Features.UseFipsCompliantChecksums='False'|
Features.ShowNonElevatedWarnings='True'|
Features.ShowDownloadProgress='True'|
Features.StopOnFirstPackageFailure='False'|
Features.UseRememberedArgumentsForUpgrades='False'|
Features.ScriptsCheckLastExitCode='False'|
ListCommand.LocalOnly='False'|
ListCommand.IncludeRegistryPrograms='False'|ListCommand.PageSize='25'|
ListCommand.Exact='False'|ListCommand.ByIdOnly='False'|
ListCommand.IdStartsWith='False'|ListCommand.OrderByPopularity='False'|
ListCommand.ApprovedOnly='False'|
ListCommand.DownloadCacheAvailable='False'|
ListCommand.NotBroken='False'|
ListCommand.IncludeVersionOverrides='False'|
UpgradeCommand.FailOnUnfound='False'|
UpgradeCommand.FailOnNotInstalled='False'|
UpgradeCommand.NotifyOnlyAvailableUpgrades='False'|
UpgradeCommand.ExcludePrerelease='False'|
NewCommand.AutomaticPackage='False'|
NewCommand.UseOriginalTemplate='False'|SourceCommand.Command='unknown'|
SourceCommand.Priority='0'|SourceCommand.BypassProxy='False'|
SourceCommand.AllowSelfService='False'|
FeatureCommand.Command='unknown'|
ConfigCommand.Command='unknown'|PinCommand.Command='unknown'|
Proxy.BypassOnLocal='True'| 2017-04-26 11:47:33,095 [DEBUG] - _
Chocolatey:ChocolateyInstallCommand - Normal Run Mode _ 2017-04-26
11:47:33,102 [INFO ] - Installing the following packages: 2017-04-26
11:47:33,111 [INFO ] - choco 2017-04-26 11:47:33,119 [INFO ] - By
installing you accept licenses for the packages. 2017-04-26
11:47:33,517 [WARN ] - [NuGet] An error occurred while loading
packages from 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/': The remote server
returned an error: (403) Forbidden. 2017-04-26 11:47:33,531 [ERROR] -
choco not installed. The package was not found with the source(s)
listed.  If you specified a particular version and are receiving this
message, it is possible that the package name exists but the version
does not.  Version: ""  Source(s): "https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/"
2017-04-26 11:47:33,558 [WARN ] -  Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages.
1 packages failed.  See the log for details
(C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log). 2017-04-26
11:47:33,569 [INFO ] -  2017-04-26 11:47:33,577 [ERROR] - Failures
2017-04-26 11:47:33,586 [ERROR] -  - choco - choco not installed. The
package was not found with the source(s) listed.  If you specified a
particular version and are receiving this message, it is possible that
the package name exists but the version does not.  Version: "" 
Source(s): "https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/" 2017-04-26 11:47:33,596
[WARN ] -  Enjoy using Chocolatey? Explore more amazing features to
take your  experience to the next level at 
https://chocolatey.org/compare 2017-04-26 11:47:33,606 [DEBUG] -
Sending message 'PostRunMessage' out if there are subscribers...
2017-04-26 11:47:33,613 [DEBUG] - Exiting with 1
```

Comment: The error is `(403) Forbidden`, hence no download, hence nothing to unzip with 7-Zip.

Comment: That makes sense. Why do you think I am being "Forbidden"? And what does that have to do with the "completely offline install" not working?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use 'chocolatey' so I can't comment on that. You might ask whoever wrote that tool.

Comment: Crazy question - you have Chocolatey already installed - why are you running the install again?

Comment: I am not able to use chocolatey to install anything, so it seems like there must be something wrong with the installation. I've run the install and upgrade commands repeatedly because the installation instructions that I linked to recommend that.  I get errors when I run them as you can see in the log

Comment: Are you maybe subject to a proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that most likely you are running into a SSL/TLS issue. We just switched the certificates out on Monday, and the old certificate expired on Tuesday. My guess is that you need to update your certificates or you have a caching of the old certificate for some reason.

The other possibility is there is a proxy in the way that is stopping you from reaching out.

Comment: @MattVS By CloudFlare then? Something we can do to fix that?

Comment: Yes by CloudFlare. We immediately took care of the malware that got us flagged and I've been working to get us whitelisted for 8 days straight. That is definitely why our IP is "forbidden" though.

Comment: If you use the contact form on the website, we can see about getting you whitelisted.

Comment: Thank you, I have done so. I should have thought contacting you all directly

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about your chocolatey.config. Appears you got blocked but for anyone visiting this question these are the relevant keys you'll need to fill out. Unless you've been a bad boy and got your IP black listed.

```
  <config>
<add key="cacheLocation" value="" description="Cache location if not TEMP folder." />
<add key="containsLegacyPackageInstalls" value="true" description="Install has packages installed prior to 0.9.9 series." />
<add key="commandExecutionTimeoutSeconds" value="2700" description="Default timeout for command execution. '0' for infinite (starting in 0.10.4)." />
<add key="proxy" value="" description="Explicit proxy location. Available in 0.9.9.9+." />
<add key="proxyUser" value="" description="Optional proxy user. Available in 0.9.9.9+." />
<add key="proxyPassword" value="" description="Optional proxy password. Encrypted. Available in 0.9.9.9+." />
<add key="webRequestTimeoutSeconds" value="30" description="Default timeout for web requests. Available in 0.9.10+." />
<add key="proxyBypassList" value="" description="Optional proxy bypass list. Comma separated. Available in 0.10.4+." />
<add key="proxyBypassOnLocal" value="true" description="Bypass proxy for local connections. Available in 0.10.4+." />
```